# UITableView render cells during scrollToRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a tableview full of image cells and I want it to automatically scroll slowly to the top of the tableview, while showing all the cells in between the bottom & top of the tableview.

The problem is that the tableview only renders the cells at the very top, leaving all the cells in between blank.

How can I render everything in between that?

Code:

```
-(void)animateTableWithPosts:(WSPostCollection *)posts {
    [self.table.tblMinutes setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.table.tblMinutes.contentSize.height - self.table.tblMinutes.bounds.size.height) animated:false];
    [self.table.tblMinutes layoutIfNeeded];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:30.0 delay:3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        [self.table.tblMinutes scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:false];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: UITableViews update asynchronously, and as little as possible.  For the most part, it won't update while you're scrolling, and it doesn't matter if the scrolling is initiated by the user or the app itself.  You would have to animate in steps, giving time for the cells to fill in before triggering the next scroll.  That would naturally leave you with very jerky scrolling.

Comment: Table views do load content while scrolling when user triggered, the UI would look terrible if it didn't @Avi. Have you tried scrolling by setting the content offset? I expect Avi is right that you may need to update the content offset repeatedly as I expect the table loads content based on the scroll end position compared to the start position and an expectation that the transition is constant time...

Comment: Have you tried `animated:true` instead of `false`?

Comment: @Paulw11 `animated:true` won't work for what I'm trying to achieve. It'll scroll too fast

Comment: @Wain's answer worked pretty well. Took a little tweaking but it looks great. Now I have another problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33766993/stop-a-uitableview-from-automatically-scrolling