# Stop a UITableView from automatically scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, ios-animations

I have a UITableView that I'm autoscrolling with `setContentOffset`. Like so:

```
 CGFloat point = self.table.tblMinutes.contentSize.height - self.table.tblMinutes.bounds.size.height;

    [self.table.tblMinutes setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, point) animated:false];
    [self.table.tblMinutes layoutIfNeeded];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:20.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        [self.table.tblMinutes setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, point - 500) animated:false];
    } completion:nil];
```

What I want to achieve is for the scrolling to smoothly slow down and stop. I haven't been able to achieve that.

Calling `[self.table.tblMinutes.layer removeAllAnimations]` stops the animation, but moves the contentOffset for some reason, not achieving what I want.

I tried using the `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` option in a animation but that did nothing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why aren't you calling `setContentOffset:animated:`?

Comment: @matt I'm calling it within a `[UIView animateWithDuration]` block, with the `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` option. Nothing happens

Comment: Sorry, I'm just confused about what you're trying to achieve. Smoothly slow down and stop, that sounds like a custom animation curve, so why isn't that all you need? In other words I don't see the point of your two-stage linear plus completion. Just animate to where you want to animate to...?

Comment: @matt I removed the linear + completion. It's not important. Basically the slowdown occurs after the user taps a "notification".

Comment: Ah. So you mean, you are _in the middle_ of an animation and you want to _change_ it suddenly while it's still going on?

Comment: @matt Exactly. Nothing I've tried has worked well :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a subset of the classic problem of interrupting an existing animation and replacing it with a different animation.

The problem here is that if you *merely* remove the existing animation, you will jump to the end of that animation.

The solution to that is to consult the *presentation layer* and set the layer to that position before removing the existing animation. *Now* you are starting from midstream and can apply another animation.

Comment: Ahhhh interesting. I'll give this a shot

Comment: For an example, look here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch04p133cancelAnimation/ch17p484cancelAnimation/ViewController.swift Work your way through the examples; I think case 3 is closest to what you are after, and you should be able to use it as a basis.

Comment: Works like a charm . Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Kyle Truscott's excellent blog post](http://keighl.com/post/decelerate-uiscrollview-ala-ultravisual/) about this for UIScrollView. UITableView inherits from UIScrollView, so in theory, it should work.

Comment: No, I don't see how that's relevant. That's for _manual_ scrolling, and it's what table view's already do.